Creality LD-002R cannot print model - does not match predicted resolution

Good afternoon. Can you tell me why when I click on the model to print, on the printer, Creality ld 002r, the printer has chitubox 4.4.3 v1 LSDK1/1620*2650 firmware. Error displayed:

The cutout does not match the predicted resolution of -1440.

And the model is not printed. How to fix this?
No models have been printed yet. They removed the fastener carelessly and hit the old one. Now they have installed this one a.aliexpress.com/_EytjKzj.

Welcome, in order to get your question answered, you might want to improve the question. As is, it could be interpreted as a low quality question and may not receive the attention it needs, please provide a proper question title, structure the question and add relevant tags.

Can you fill in the background?   Like, did you buy this printer new?  Is it this printer:   https://www.creality3dofficial.com/products/ld-002r-lcd-resin-3d-printer   ?   Has this printer ever functioned correctly ?

Yes, such a printer.

Did you slice the model? It reads like the sliced model is defect

Everything was done, the model was created, then sliced and saved. Tried using chitubox from version 1.6 to 1.9. The result is the same.

found. Error code 1440.

Your slicer is misconfigured.
You have set up the slicer not fitting to your printer. Error 1440 is Bad resolution error. Set the slicer correctly according to the Chitubox manual.
According to the firmware, you have a 1620x2560 pixel bed. You need to set your slicer to that setting.
If that is set up properly, then your printer's firmware is misconfigured and you should download and install the latest firmware for your printer from Creality.

Thank you very much for the explanation. I will try to do everything according to your advice. Tell me another question. In the settings of this printer, do I need to change the rise from 0.10 to less before printing? In the menu tools?

not necessarily.

@user48954 that's a different question. Ask it separately please.
